# Nodejs not running batch file or command

Tags: node.js

I have the following nodejs script:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var nrc = require('node-run-cmd');

app.get('/ipad_charger/on', function (req, res) 
{
    nrc.run('tuya-cli set --id my_id --key my_key -s --set true')
    res.send("ipad charger on");
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on 3000');
});
```

I created a windows service using `qckwinsvc` which starts the script as expected.

Looks like I can not run any file or command from node , but I can run a simple command like `shutdown`.

I tried with spawn
`spawn('cmd.exe', ['/K', 'tuya-cli set --id my_id --key my_key -s --set true']);` as well as running a batch with `child_process.exec()`.

I must say that if I log in on Windows (the script above as I said starts as a service before logging in) and manually start the node script using `node index.js` with a different port **IT WORKS**, but that is not acceptable in my case...

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why are you using `qckwinsvc`, why not run it the normal `node index.js` way?

Comment: Because with `qckwinsvc` I configured it to start before logging in on windows.

Comment: so whats the problem again? I didn't understand this line: 
> Looks like I can not run any file from node or command, but I can run a simple command like shutdown.

Comment: `spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'SHUTDOWN -r -t 0']);` works for example, but the ones mentioned do not work (when I tried to run a batch it did not even start running it)